# Vue.js. Data property undefined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to access my data property in my *Vue.js* component. Looks like I'm missing something obvious.

Here is a short version of my code. `StoreFilter.vue` is a wrapper for [matfish2/vue-tables-2](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2).

```
<template>
    <store-filter :selected.sync="storeIds"></store-filter>
</template>

<script>
    import StoreFilter from './Filters/StoreFilter';

    export default {
        components: {
            StoreFilter
        },
        data() {
            return {
                options : {
                    requestFunction(data) {

                        console.log(this.storeIds); //undefined

                        return axios.get('/api/orders', {
                            params: data
                        }).catch(function (e) {
                            this.dispatch('error', e);
                        }.bind(this));
                    },
                },
                storeIds: [],
            }
        },
        watch     : {
            storeIds(storeIds) {
                this.refreshTable();
            }
        },
        methods   : {
            refreshTable() {
                this.$refs.table.refresh();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

How to get `storeIds` from `requestFunction`?

Comment: maybe you should put that in `methods` instead? and if for whatever reason you decide that you need to put it in `data` use fat arrow function instead i.e. `requestFunction: (data) => {}`

Comment: @ A. Lau I can't use `methods`, cause it's a [predefined function](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2#custom-request-function), but your solution helped. Please, write it as an answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure, see rewrite below.

```
data() {
  let dataHolder = {};
  dataHolder.storeIds = [];

  dataHolder.options = {
    requestFunction(data) {

        // closure
        console.log(dataHolder.storeIds); // not undefined

        return axios.get('/api/orders', {
            params: data
        }).catch(function (e) {
            this.dispatch('error', e);
        }.bind(this));
    }
  }

  return dataHolder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `created()` way to handle this.

```
export default {
  // whatever you got here
  data () {
    return {
      options: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    axios.get('/api/orders', { some: params }).then(response => this.options = response.data)
  }
}
```

Comment: It'd probably be better to initialize `options: null` so you can use `v-if` to check.

Comment: I could also use the `Object.keys(options).length > 0` to check. I mean it's really either or here for personal preference. Of course, I am open to find out if `null` or the `Object.keys()` method is cleaner and better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't use methods, cause it's a [predefined function](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2#custom-request-function).

Comment: I am not using method here. I’m using the `created ()` way

Comment: @RuChernChong Once again. I can't put this function anywhere, but `options`. And @A.Lau has already solved this problem.